# Can growisofs or dd be forced to erase a CD-R?

Tags: command-line, dd, iso

I need to securely erase a CD without marks of intentional data loss (can't scratch or break it), so I was wondering: how could I use growisofs or dd to burn all non burned spaces in the disk to render it unreadable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

growisofs works only with DVD or BD media. dd cannot write to unformatted
CD (only CD-RW but not CD-R could be formatted).

A CD-R medium might be still writable (aka "appendable") on its unused
area. But it cannot be blanked in any way. You may only overwrite the
unused area by some harmless bytes. (Question is why you want to do
that.)

For that you need a CD capable burn program, like cdrecord, wodim, cdrskin,
or xorriso. First check whether the CD-R is still writable:

```
prog=cdrskin

$prog -v dev=/dev/sr0 -msinfo
```

You may use "cdrecord", "wodim", "xorrecord", or "xorriso -as cdrecord"
instead of "cdrskin".

If the CD-R is still writable, you will get two comma separated numbers
on standard output.
If it is not writable any more (aka "closed") then you will get no
output on stdout but rather some error message like:

```
cdrskin: FATAL : -msinfo can only operate on appendable (i.e. -multi) discs

cdrecord: Cannot get next writable address for 'invisible' track.

wodim: Cannot get next writable address for 'invisible' track.

xorriso : FAILURE : Output medium is not appendable. Cannot obtain -msinfo.
```

If you get the numbers, you may burn to the medium with random bytes
until the burner throws an error because it is full:

```
prog=cdrskin

dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M | $prog -v dev=/dev/sr0 -eject -
```

or if all zeros is good enough for your purpose:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M | $prog -v dev=/dev/sr0 -eject -
```

But as said, why would you want to do that ?

Have a nice day :)

Thomas